# What action does the compiler error "needs -Onone swift optimisation level" require in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

Reproduction steps:

1. create new SwiftUI project;
2. split into two targets, release and
   debug;
3. view preview of release target View struct.

Comment: It seems that this error can be removed by editing the target's scheme so that its build configuration is set to Debug not Release, but it takes some quote/unquote mental dexterity to label that as a fix

Comment: Any more luck solving this one?

Comment: I haven't returned to it yet @C.Skjerdal I'm afraid, so no

Comment: I ended up finding a single spot that was targeting iOS 13.1, while the rest was set to iOS 13.0.. solved it right away. Very misleading compiler error on my end anyway. Weird though since you are creating a new project, I didn't have any issues that way.